# Getting "Member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, constructor

I knew constructors from Java and have now a C# project. Syntax in both languages is very similar, so I thought this shouldn't be a problem:

```
class ShapeItems
{
    public String masterName = "";
    public String stencilName = "";
    public Double coordY = 0.0;
    public Double coordX = 0.0;
    public String shapeText = "";

    public void ShapeItems(String mN, String sN, Double X,  Double Y, String sT)
    {
        this.masterName = mN;
        this.stencilName = sN;
        this.coordX = X;
        this.coordY = Y;
        this.shapeText = sT;
    }
}
```

But as I wrote the constructor, I received the error:

> Member Names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

I've seen some others with this problems here, but the answers won't fix my problem.

Maybe someone here has a hint for me to solve this issue?

Comment: remove `void` from constructor signature

Comment: It been awhile since I've written Java, but I don't think constructors in Java start with `void`.

Comment: it is not related to the void (and yes the void is wrong also in java :D ... my mistake)

Comment: Are you still getting the error after a rebuild?

Comment: ok noob question why do i need to rebuild on those errors? there is eclipse more easier :D

Comment: after rebuild error is gone thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a constructor but a method: `void`. Remove the word `void` and it should work.

So

```
public ShapeItems(params) { }
```

instead of

```
public void ShapeItems(params) { }
```

Comment: this doesn't change anything :(

Comment: i've edited my code like you said, but the error stays for the constructor with parameters.

Comment: rebuild if problem persists, however normally this should not be an issue.

Comment: hi shishdem, thanks for your answer, i rebuild it already and it works now :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove "void" from constructor signature:

```
public ShapeItems(...) { }
```

Comment: this doesn't change anything :(

Comment: i've edited my code like you said, but the error stays for the constructor with parameters.

Comment: Your code without "void" compiles fine. Your code with "void" produces the exact error you showed. If your are atill getting this error after removing "void", you have other code with the same problem somewhere else. What line does compiler flag with the error?

Comment: Hi Igor, the Code is flag the 2. Constructor as wrong even after the void was removed... but what i didn't knew is that i need to rebuild the whole project to fix this problem... now void is removed and project rebuild and it work... thanks all for your help. :-=)